# How can I include vue and axios in a 3rd party template?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

So I purchased the Vuexy template. I am using the HTML + Laravel version of the template. I would like to use vue.js and axios with this template but I am having issues. I can't even seem to get vue.js and axios loaded properly.

In the template, they provide a webpack.mix.js and a \resources\js\core\app.js file. The webpack the template provides does not reference the standard laravel app.js. I would like to use vue.js and axios with this template.

When I try adding the code from bootstrap.js and app.js, I run into issues. More specifically, when I add the following code to the top of the core/app.js file, I am able to load vue components but if i navigate to a page without any vue components then I run receive "app.js:1578 [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app"

```
window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('account-password', require('../components/Password.vue').default)

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

The full webpack is on pastebin at:  https://pastebin.com/FCs6G1RD
The full core\app.js is on pastebin at:  https://pastebin.com/jybt1WD3

So I guess my question boils down to how can I properly add vue.js and axios to work with this template? I am completely stuck.

Thank you.

Comment: I wanted to add, if I try including the require axios and vue at the top of the core\app.js, I then get:  "cannot find element: #app" and "cannot read propery 'menu' of undefined" and nothing seems to work right.

Comment: Is there an element with ```id="app"``` on the page? Vue binds itself to an element in the dom with the id you specify. Vue functionality will only work inside of that element.

Comment: Do you even have an #app in your public/index.html?

Comment: @KurtFriars There is an id="app" on the pages where I am using the component, but on pages where I am not using it, there is not.

I think the issue is how webpack is compiling everything together. I just am not sure how that needs to be done correctly.

Comment: Just a quick update. I used the id="app" on the template part and that seems to have fixed the issue. So I guess I will move on and just hope everything else works as it should.